# String contains with wildcard detection without indexOf method

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, wildcard

I want to check whether a String contains a pattern similar to what String.contains() does but with wildcard (*) detection as well.

A pattern can have none, single or multiple wildcards and each occurrence can match for zero or more characters.

If * is preceded by a \ character, then the * should be considered as a regular character.

Examples:

```
"abc" <- "" result: true
"abcd" <- "a*d" result: true
"a*cd" <- "a\\*cd" result: true
"abc" <- "A" result: false
"" <- "*" result: true
"abcd" <- "**a**b****c***d***" result: true
"\\" <- "\\" result: true
"***" <- "*\\**\\*\\*" result: true
"abcd*abcde" <- "a*\\*abcd" result: true
```

I've found this code snippet that somewhat works. Added null and empty string/pattern check and most of the cases work. Except for the wildcard cases.

```java
public static void stringMatch(String text, String pattern)
    {
  
        int len_t = text.length();
        int len_p = pattern.length();
  
        int k = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
  
        // loop to find out the position Of searched pattern
        for (i = 0; i <= (len_t - len_p); i++) {
  
            for (j = 0; j < len_p; j++)
            {
                if (text.charAt(i + j) != pattern.charAt(j))
                    break;
            }
            
            if (j == len_p)
            {
                k++;
                System.out.println("Pattern Found at Position: " + i);
            }
        }
        
        if (k == 0)
            System.out.println("No Match Found!");
        else
            System.out.println("Total Instances Found = " + k);
    }
```

Comment: You're really reinventing regexes. You should be *using* them with ```String.matches```

Comment: In other cases I'd do that, but now I have to do it with character matching.

Comment: Some of your examples do not fit your pattern rules, e.g. `"a*cd" <- "a\\*d" result: true` the pattern does not contain any wildcard, that is why the result should be false because of the "c" in your string. Please correct your examples.

Comment: You are right @MichaelKatt, I've fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with two specific wildcards, the asterisk (*) and the question mark (?). The asterisk is for any number of arbitrary characters and the question mark for any single character.

You can possible use the following method to carry out the task. It utilizes the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method by manipulating the supplied criteria:

```
/**
 * Returns either true or false if a string contains a WildCard match. 
 * Asterisks (*) are used for an arbitrary number of characters pattern 
 * matching and the question mark character (?) is used* for exactly one 
 * character pattern matching.
 * 
 * <b>Simple Example Usage:</b><pre>
 * 
 *     boolean tf1 = wildCardWordMatch("this", "th*");  // true
 *     boolean tf2 = wildCardWordMatch("this", "toa*"); // false</pre>
 *
 * @param StringWord (String) String to test.<br>
 * 
 * @param criteria   (String) The wildcard pattern to test.<br>
 *
 * @return (boolean) True if the string matches the criteria wildcard pattern 
 * and False if not.
 */
public static boolean wildCardWordMatch(String stringWord, String criteria) {
    if (stringWord == null || criteria == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }

    // Check for escaped wildcard characters.
    boolean hasEscape = false;
    if (criteria.contains("\\\\")) { 
        criteria = criteria.replace("\\\\", "~ee~");
        hasEscape = true;
    }
    if (criteria.contains("\\*") || criteria.contains("\\?")) {
        hasEscape = true;
        criteria = criteria.replace("\\*", "~||~");
        criteria = criteria.replace("\\?", "~!!~");
    }
    
    criteria = criteria.replace("?", ".{1}").replace("*", (criteria.endsWith("*") ? ".*" : ".*?"));
    
    if (hasEscape) {
        criteria = criteria.replace("~||~", "\\*");
        criteria = criteria.replace("~!!~", "\\?*");
        criteria = criteria.replace("~ee~", "\\\\");
    }
    
    boolean res = false;
    try {
        res = stringWord.matches(criteria);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(System.lineSeparator() + 
                "wildCardWordMatch() Method Error! Invalid Criteria " +
                "supplied! (" + criteria + ")" + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return res;
}
```

The following tests were done:

```
Java String   Criteria              Result
========================================== 
"abc"         ""                    true
"abcd"        "a*d"                 true
"a*cd"        "a\\*cd"              true
"abc"         "A"                   false (not enough characters and wrong case)
""            "*"                   true
"abcd"        "**a**b****c***d***"  true  (Works but is pointless with so many *'s)
"abcd"        "*a*b*c*d*"           true  (Works and is same as above)
"abcd"        a??d                  true
"abcd         "a???d"               false (too many ?'s)
"\\"          "\\\\"                true
"***"         "*\\**\\*\\*"         true
"abcd*abcde"  "a*\\*abcd"           false (No 'e' in criteria)
"abcd*abcde"  "a*\\*abcde"          true
"abcd"        "????"                true  
"abcd"        "???"                 false (Not enough ?'s)
"\\\\abc"     "\\\\\\\\*"           true
"\\\\abc"     "\\\\\\\\???"         true
"abc\\\\"     "??\\\\\\\\"          false (Not enough ?'s)
"abc\\\\"     "???\\\\\\\\"         true
"abc\\\\"     "a?c\\\\\\\\"         true
"abc\\\\"     "a??c\\\\\\\\"        false (too many ?'s)
"abc\\\\"     "a*c\\\\\\\\"         true
"abc\\\\"     "*\\\\\\\\"           true
"abc\\"       "*\\\\"               true
"\\abc"       "\\\\*"               true
"\\abc\\"     "\\\\*\\\\"           true
"\\abc\\"     "\\\\ac\\\\"          false (Missing the character 'b')
"\\abc\\"     "\\\\abc\\\\"         true
"\\abc\\"     "\\\\???\\\\"         true
```

**On a side:** In the examples you placed in your post, your last one is wrong. It should never be true since there is no 'e' or wildcard at the end of the criteria.

Comment: Are we sure a backslash cannot itself be escaped?  What should `\\\\*` match?

Comment: Good point. I Modified the method. `"\\\\*"` would be a match to something like `"\\whatever is here"` and `"*\\\\"` would be a match to something like `"what the\\"`. Thank you.